# Echo Variable To File Without New Lines

Tags: ffmpeg, echo

I want to get rid of new lines in Echo then suffix a file with them.

```
files=$(cat ./Temp/files.txt)
prefixedfiles=$(cat ./Temp/prefixedfiles.txt)
echo "$files" >> generatedscript
sed -e 's/^/ffmpeg -i /' generatedscript >> generatedscript2
sed 's/$/ -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -threads 10 -crf 18 /' >> 
generatedscript2
echo "$prefixedfiles" > generatedscript3
```

E.g files.txt

```
./Testing/blank.mp4
./More Testing/Test.mkv
```

E.g prefixedfiles.txt

```
../Encoded/Testing/blank.mp4
../Encoded/More Testing/Test.mkv
```

Expected output: generatedscript3

```
ffmpeg -i ./Testing/blank.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -threads 10 -crf 18 ../Encoded/More Testing/blank.mp4
ffmpeg -i ./More Testing/Test.mkv -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -threads 10 -crf 18 ../Encoded/More Testing/Test.mkv
```

Comment: There appear to logic errors in your script (removing new lines can be done with echo -n but I dont think this will help you).  Why do you have both files.txt and prefixedfiles.txt, rather then a single file with separation if required?  Will the path on prefixedfiles.txt change on a per file bases? What do you think the second line is trying to do?   (I ask these questions because I suspect the way you are trying to build the script is impractical - you probably need to iterate over $files  on a line-by-line basis. No point in helping write it until I understand the constraints.

Comment: 1. The reason the 2 are seperate is because to be able to add "-vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -threads 10 -crf 18" in the middle of the 2 I would need to take down the amount of characters needed for each line and put it in the middle with sed.

Comment: 2. Yes except for "../Encoded"

Comment: 3. I'm assuming you mean "sed -e 's/^/ffmpeg -i /' generatedscript >> generatedscript2" it adds ffmpeg -i to the front of every line to tell ffmpeg that is the input. If you were talking about "prefixedfiles=$(cat ./Temp/prefixedfiles.txt)" it is supposed to be a variable for bash to read out because cat will just output to a new line.

Comment: bash = echo in 3.

Comment: Btw prefixedfiles.txt and files.txt are generated seperately I didn't include my entire script the entire script is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ninsto/FFmpegScripts/master/copythenencode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments, I think the logic of the script you provided is flawed - specifically I don't see how sed is able to combine the 2 input files on a per row basis (I don't think it works the way you think it does)

I've come up with an alternative solution for you -

```
#! /bin/bash

export IFS=$'\n'

(
for LINE in `paste Temp/files.txt Temp/prefixedfiles.txt`
do
    F1=`echo $LINE | cut -f1`
    F2=`echo $LINE | cut -f2`    
    echo "ffmpeg -i $F1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec copy -threads 10 -crf 18 $F2"

done 
) > generatedscript3
```

Explanation:

The export IFS line changes the file separation character to newline - this means that spaces in the files will be correctly handled.

The magic occurs in the for LINE loop - the "paste" command merges the 2 files into a single tab separated output, which is then processed line-by-line.

F1 and F2 separate the 2 parts of the input into variables, which are then printed using the echo line.

This whole output is captured into a file called generatedscript3 (because the loop and echo is between brackets)